# mobile-detect pixel size device change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, responsive-design

Can please somebody tell at what screen size will [mobile-detect](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js) npm package report tablet, mobile. For example, if width is below 320px it's mobile. I cannot find this information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From mobile-detect's documentation, it looks like it is focused on **device** detection, so it allows you to target specific devices.

If you want to detect pixel width for **styling** purposes, then you can simply use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

If you need to do programmatic things as opposed to just styles, then you can use javascript's native `window.innerWidth` method, or use jQuery for `window.width` and `window.resize` methods (for screen rotation, etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanna stop desktop responsive customization at some pixel size. For example, someone is on desktop and starts shrinking the screen. The elements start to rearange to accomodate the new size but at one point user will hit my body minWidth css property and elements will stop to rearange. I wanted to put minWidth to pixel size that mobile-detect figures that request is coming from mobile. But if it's not working based on screen size then I need to do something else. I need this use case because of server side rendering on React. When you use media queries everything is SSR rendered.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk I've never used React server-side rendering, so can't help you with that part. If you are using node, there are other NPM packages that will help you with screen size/resize detection. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-size